# Derivative of a complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, complex-numbers

I am taking the derivative of a complex function and I would like to see if my process is correct. Let $g(z)=(z^*)^3$ and $z=x+yi$, for $x,y \in R$ and $i=\sqrt(-1)$. So $g(z)=x^3-3x^2yi-3xy^2+y^3i$. This we can split up into $u=Re(g(z))=x^3-3xy^2$ and $v=Im(g(z))=-3x^2y+y^3$. In order to get the derivative we need to prove if the function is analytic and thereby satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Observe,
$$u_x=3x^2-3y^2; u_y=-6xy $$
$$v_x=-6xy; v_y=-3x^2+3y^2$$

Since $u_x\ne v_y$ and $u_y\ne -v_x$, the function is not analytic. However when we take the second derivatives of each, we can show it is harmonic. What is it that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong here.

The real and/or imaginary part of a non-analytic function may very well be harmonic. Another example: $f(x+iy) = (x^2-y^2) + ix$.

(In fact your function is anti-analytic, i.e. $g(z) = f(\bar z)$ for an analytic $f$, and such functions always have harmonic real and imaginary parts, and actually satisfy a pair of equations similar to Cauchy-Riemann's. You can probably work out the details of this if you want.)